# Event handler can't be triggered in ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here are TextBox and is's event handler:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_users" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_users_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rpt_users_ItemDataBound"><ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="c0">
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "daysleft") %>' OnTextChanged="Unnamed_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>

protected void Unnamed_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var repeaterItem = (sender as TextBox).NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
    var hiddenFieldKey = repeaterItem.FindControl("LoginField") as HiddenField;
    DataTable data = ViewState["Data"] as DataTable;
    var dataRow = data.Rows.Find(hiddenFieldKey.Value);
    var userName = (dataRow[0].ToString()).Replace("'", "''");
    ... //more actions below
}
```

This event handler can't be triggered now. It worked fine sometimes ago, but recently I deleted Page_Init event handler from code-behind and replace it with Page_Load event handler. Can these facts be connected? Which conditions should be complied to make this handler reachable?

Comment: I think TextChanged Event doesn't work in Web Applications, it works only with Windows Form Applications... You can rather use JavaScript or jQuery for the same.....

Comment: Are you keeping this Texbox inside the DataGrid or ListView Control or any other data binding control? Can you post the markup?

Comment: @AbhayPrince `TextChanged` exists in Web Forms http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: @Deepu, it is placed in Repeater. I shared more details.

Comment: Can you share code of Page_Load mehod (code that was in Page_Init)?

Comment: @splash27 I moved the code to inside !page.ispost back check... it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeater data binding should be inside not is postback condition

```
public class Test
{
    public string daysleft { get; set; }
}

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindRepeaterItems();
        }
    }

    private void BindRepeaterItems()
    {
         var items = new List<Test>
         {
                new Test {daysleft = "Deepu"},
                new Test {daysleft = "Darsh"}
         };
         rpt_users.DataSource = items;
         rpt_users.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Unnamed_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var repeaterItem = (sender as TextBox).NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
        var hiddenFieldKey = repeaterItem.FindControl("LoginField") as HiddenField;
    }
}

<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_users" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "daysleft") %>' OnTextChanged="Unnamed_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/><br />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: It solved the problem with handler, but cause another problem. It makes page selector dissapear after every partial postback. For example, I changed value in textbox or selected second page in page selector, and page selector dissapears.

Comment: if your first problem solved, can you mark up vout / answer so that it would be useful for others :)

Comment: You mean second page or second textbox control?

Comment: I mean second problem. if I use (!IsPostBack) over all code in Page_load, some controls such as page selector and sort type selector (based on DropDownList) stop work. Which part of code should be placed inside of (!IsPostBack) statement? Only `rpt_users.DataSource = items; rpt_users.DataBind();` ? Or data preparation also must be inside?

Comment: check the modified code... call BindRepeaterItems() method when you needed for sort / any other place